# OS X Keychain's Password Assistant feature via Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

OS X's Keychain has a Password Assistant feature that suggest passwords based on user criteria (e.g. Length = 18 and FIPS-181 compliant).

I want to access this feature via bash.  My specific interest is requesting generation of a password with my desired length and complexity attributes, then adding that password item to a specific keychain.

The OS X security CLI app solves the second part, but not the initial password generation part.

man security didn't list anything regarding the Password Assistant feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you not use a different password generator such as [APG](http://www.adel.nursat.kz/apg/)?  That appears to do everything you want, and is available on MacPorts and Fink.

Answer (score 4):

While no official Apple solution appears to exist, there is a reverse-engineered library, available as a command line tool, that recreates all of the functionality available in the GUI Password Assistant.

See this link (updated as of April 2014): https://bitbucket.org/anders/sf-pwgen or https://github.com/anders/pwgen

The developer, @anders-bergh, makes the source (including Xcode project) available, and provides a download of the binary, which can be executed in the Terminal (https://bitbucket.org/anders/sf-pwgen/downloads).

The binary can also be installed with brew:`brew install sf-pwgen`.

From the project page:

> **sf-pwgen** is an example CLI application which generates passwords:

```
usage: ./sf-pwgen [options]

Option:          Meaning:
  -a, --algorithm  Available algorithms: memorable, random
                   letters, alphanumeric, numbers.
  -c, --count      The number of passwords to generate.
                   The default is `memorable'.
  -l, --length     Desired length of the generated passwords.
  -L, --language   Generate passwords in a specified language.
                   Languages: en, de, es, fr, it, nl, pt, jp.
                   Note that this feature is broken and will
                   produce garbage, bug: rdar://14889281
  -v, --version    Print the version number and exit.
  -h, --help       Prints this message.
```